# Closure Table (Moving Subtrees)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi I have a database design of

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| referral_id | referrent_id | level |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

In my database, I have a the rows of data like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 4 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
```

Basically the tree is

```
  / 2
1 - 3
  \ 4
```

And I'm trying to move 3 to be under 2

```
  / 2 - 3
1 - 4
```

My implementation:

```
public function changeReferrer(Member $newReferrer) {
        $oldReferrer = $this->getReferrer(1); // this retrieves the ancestor one level up
        DB::select('DELETE a FROM Referrer_Referent AS a
                    JOIN Referrer_Referent as d ON a.referent_id = d.referent_id
                    LEFT JOIN Referrer_Referent AS x
                    ON x.referrer_id = d.referrer_id AND x.referent_id = a.referrer_id
                    WHERE d.referrer_id = '.$oldReferrer->id.'
                    AND x.referrer_id IS NULL');

        DB::select('INSERT into Referrer_Referent (referrer_id, referent_id, level)
                    SELECT supertree.referrer_id, subtree.referent_id, supertree.level + subtree.level + 1
                    FROM Referrer_Referent as supertree JOIN Referrer_Referent as subtree
                    WHERE subtree.referrer_id = '.$oldReferrer->id.'
                    AND supertree.referent_id = '.$newReferrer->id);
    }
```

So I would call my function as `$user3->changeReferrer($user2);` But I'm getting these errors:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: INSERT into Referrer_Referent (referrer_id, referent_id, level) SELECT supertree.referrer_id, subtree.referent_id, supertree.level + subtree.level + 1 FROM Referrer_Referent as supertree JOIN Referrer_Referent as subtree WHERE subtree.referrer_id = 1 AND supertree.referent_id = 2)

Attaching this [blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/) as reference.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do this tree using mysql. Why don't you load your root level (id 1 probably), then load the referral relationship recursivelly to get each level?

Comment: Does running the select statement only gets you the results you wanted?

Comment: @Ibu Which select statement?

Comment: Inside the insert statement. I meant if you only run the select part, does it produce the result you want?

Comment: I'm able to do my inserts and retrieving my descendants and ancestors so far. The only problem now is changing the subtree to another

Comment: Ok, I just have to change `$oldReferrer->id` to `$this->id`. It's supposed to the current ID not the ancestor of the current user. Thanks @Ibu, your suggestion made my realize my mistake.

Comment: Glad I could help